# apex:actionFunction redirecting to URL with only the visualforce page on it

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, actionfunction

I am calling the actionFunction from javascript. I tried having return false; after the call as is suggested on a couple other questions I found but nothing works. I tried specifying the reRender prop for the actionFunction but it just redirects to a non-existent URL. Here is the action function:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="searchEvents" action="{!searchEvents}">
    <apex:param name="searchTerm" assignTo="{!searchTerm}" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

I am just calling it like so:

```
searchEvents("searchTerm string");
```

Comment: If you've already tried the most common solutions (which should work), you're doing something else wrong. We need to see more of your JavaScript.

Comment: The page is embedded within a standard record detail page layout, maybe that is the cause. There is no other javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The `actionFunction` will look like this and use `reRender` property.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function testFunction()
      {
           searchEvents("searchTerm string");
      }        
</script>


<apex:actionFunction name="searchEvents" action="{!searchEvents}" reRender="yourForm">
    <apex:param id="searchTermId" name="searchTerm" assignTo="{!searchTerm}" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

**Controller**

```
public String searchTerm {get;set;}
public void searchEvents()
{    
    System.debug('searchTerm=' +   searchTerm);     
}
```

Comment: What do I put in the reRender property? An id?

Comment: `reRender` will be Id

Comment: I just get a Salesforce error page with "URL no longer exists". This visualforce page is embedded in a record detail page layout if that makes a difference.

Comment: I think becuase of embedding it is giving error

Comment: Okay, what would be the way to go about calling an apex controller function from an embedded visualforce page?

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:actionFunction name="searchEvents" action="{!searchEvents}">
<apex:param name="searchTerm" assignTo="{!searchTerm}" value="" 
reRender="panel"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:outputPanel Id="panel">
<apex:commandButton id="subId" onClick="searchEvents("searchTerm string");return false;" value="Search Events" rerender="panel" /> &nbsp;
</apex:outputPanel>
```

You can use above code for actionfunction